# How to output a shell command into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a simple script:

```
stat=$(du /home/test/)
for i in "$stat"; do
folder=$("$i" | awk '{print $2}')
mail -s $folder kenny@gmail.com
done
```

I run the script in shell and the output looks like:

```
4       /home/test/.config/mc/mcedit
12      /home/test/.config/mc
16      /home/test/.config
```

I then insert echo in the script before the loop, and the output then looks like:

```
4 /home/test/.config/mc/mcedit 12 /home/test/.config/mc 16 /home/test/.config
```

This is because without double-quotes. With double-quotes output is the same as in shell. So then using double-quotes for variables in loop cycle variable $folder don't work as expected. Instead it contains all values from list.

How to resolve this?

Comment: mail command lack proper entry, are you sure this is what you expect ? why don't you pipe `du` into `awk` and `for` loop directly ?

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you look for, although not using a `for` loop but a `while` one:

```
stat=$(du /home/test/)
echo "$stat" | while read i; do
    folder=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "mail content" | mail -s $folder kenny@gmail.com
done
```

Of course, as Archemar already commented, there is no reason not to directly pipe `du` output to the loop:

```
du /home/test/ | while read i; do
    folder=$(echo "$i" | awk '{print $2}')
    echo "mail content" | mail -s $folder kenny@gmail.com
done
```

`Awk` isn't really necessary either. The script can be simplified that way:

```
du /home/test/ | while read size folder; do
    echo "mail content" | mail -s "$folder" kenny@gmail.com
done
```

As you doesn't seem to make use of the directories sizes, which is what `du` is designed to compute, you might use `find` instead:

```
find /home/test -type d | while read folder; do
    echo "mail content" | mail -s "$folder" kenny@gmail.com
done
```

Comment: I wanna insert a path as subject in mail.

in my case with double-quotes in subject looks 
/home/test/.config/mc/mcedit /home/test/.config/mc /home/test/.config

But i want send 3 mails with different subject 
ex.: 1 mail with subject /home/test/.config/mc/mcedit
2 mail with subject /home/test/.config/mc
3 mail with subject /home/test/.config

Comment: Sure, but what do you expect to put in the mail body?

Comment: Did you try my script?

Comment: Mail body contain random text. 
Yep, your version work fine. Tnx. I was thought i can use "for" loop cycle.

Comment: The `while` loop is also supremely unnecessary. You are looking simply for `du /home/^test/ | awk '{ print $2}'`

Comment: @tripleee Some sort of loop is required as one mail per directory is expected to be sent. On the other hand, `awk` and `du` aren't necessary, answer updated

Comment: Oh, I simply assumed it was a mistake to put the mail command inside the loop. One message with all the results would seem more useful. The OP's script just loops once, so it would coincidentally not be a problem there. But +1 for mind-reading skills!